# Entity Framework Can't Update Data In Table With Composite Key (Oracle)

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

We have an Oracle table that has a composite key of three columns.  These columns are correctly mapped via the Entity Framework Data Model into C# objects.  When we query a record from the database and then update a non-key column, we always receive an error saying we are trying to update the primary key (excerpt from a test is below):

```
var connection = new DbContextProvider(() => new DatabaseConnection()); 
var repo = new Repository(connection); 
var deltas = repo.Queryable<Deltas>().Where(d =>d.Volume.SubmissionId == 88921).ToList();
var deltaToUpdate = deltas.First(); 
deltaToUpdate.RecordedVolume = 0;
repo.Flush();  -- Does a context.SaveChanges() in background
```

We always receive the following:

> System.InvalidOperationException : The property 'COPY_ID' is part of
>   the object's key information and cannot be modified.

COPY_ID is part of the key but is a StoredGeneratedPettern=Identity and it is not changed in the transaction.

Any help appreciated.

Here is the full stack:

> System.InvalidOperationException : The property 'COPY_ID' is part of
>   the object's key information and cannot be modified.
>   at Data.Objects.EntityEntry.VerifyEntityValueIsEditable(StateManagerTypeMetadata typeMetadata, Int32 ordinal, String memberName)
>
> at System.Data.Objects.EntityEntry.GetAndValidateChangeMemberInfo(String entityMemberName, Object complexObject, String complexObjectMemberName, ref StateManagerTypeMetadata typeMetadata, ref String changingMemberName, ref Object changingObject)
>
> at System.Data.Objects.EntityEntry.EntityMemberChanging(String entityMemberName, Object complexObject, String complexObjectMemberName)
>
> at System.Data.Objects.EntityEntry.EntityMemberChanging(String entityMemberName)
>
> at System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateEntry.System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.IEntityChangeTracker.EntityMemberChanging(String entityMemberName)
>
> at System.Data.Objects.Internal.SnapshotChangeTrackingStrategy.SetCurrentValue(EntityEntry entry, StateManagerMemberMetadata member, Int32 ordinal, Object target, Object value)
>
> at System.Data.Objects.Internal.EntityWrapper`1.SetCurrentValue(EntityEntry entry, StateManagerMemberMetadata member, Int32 ordinal, Object target, Object value)
>
> at System.Data.Objects.EntityEntry.SetCurrentEntityValue(StateManagerTypeMetadata metadata, Int32 ordinal, Object userObject, Object newValue)
>
> at System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateEntryDbUpdatableDataRecord.SetRecordValue(Int32 ordinal, Object value)
>
> at System.Data.Objects.DbUpdatableDataRecord.SetValue(Int32 ordinal, Object value)
>
> at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.SetServerGenValue(P
>   ropagatorResult context, Object value)
>
> at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.BackPropagateServerGen(List`1 generatedValues)
>
> at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
>
> at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityAdapter.Update(IEntityStateManager entityCache)
>
> at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
>   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()

**UPDATE**
We have traced the db interactions and it appears the following SQL is being run successfully on the database, when it returns to EF the error is thrown (and the change not committed):

```
declare 
"COPY_ID" number(10,0); 
"CODS_ID" number(10,0); 
"PERIOD_ID" number(7,0); 

begin 
  update "SCHEMA"."TABLE" 
  set "COLUMN" = :p0 
  where ((("COPY_ID" = :p1) 
  and ("CODS_ID" = :p2)) 
  and ("PERIOD_ID" = :p3)) 
  returning "COPY_ID", "CODS_ID", "PERIOD_ID" into "COPY_ID", "CODS_ID",  "PERIOD_ID"; 

  open :p4 
    for select "COPY_ID" as "COPY_ID", "CODS_ID" as "CODS_ID",           "PERIOD_ID" as "PERIOD_ID" 
  from dual; 
end; 

{ :p0=[Decimal,0,Input]0, :p1=[Int32,0,Input]222222, :p2=[Int32,0,Input]22222, :p3=[Int32,0,Input]222222, :p4=[Object,0,Output]NULL }
```

Comment: Have you tried explicitly setting the key properties state to unchanged before saving the changes on the dbContext? (Just an idea... This would be my starting point). You may do it just before your `repo.Flush()`.

Comment: Hi Marcelo, we have tried: repo.GetContext().Entry(delta).Property(tsd => tsd.COPY_ID).IsModified = false; - is that what you were meaning?

Comment: Yes, or you may implement a _SavingChanges on your dbContext class. Something like this: `static void YourDBContext_SavingChanges(object sender, EventArgs e) { ObjectContext context = sender as ObjectContext;
 foreach(ObjectStateEntry entry in context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Modified))                { if (entry.Entity is YourClass) {
  if (entry.State == EntityState.Modified) {
                           entry.RejectPropertyChanges("FIRSTKEYPROPERTY");
                           entry.RejectPropertyChanges("SECONDKEYPROPERTY");
...`

Comment: In that case, you could set a breakpoint on the _SavingChanges (which should occur more closely to the SQL statement itself) and check for what's marked as changed...

Comment: The other (better) approach would be to use a profiler and try to get something out of the EF's SQL Statement (as to figure out why Oracle is throwing that error)

Comment: Can you include you class definition (if you are setting the keys with annotations) or the mappings that you are setting on ef?

Comment: I don't think it is getting to the database - have edited question to show full stack - error is from EF not Oracle I think?

Comment: @Chris yes but it would be good to know what it's trying to do regardless, to see what it is about to send to Oracle that is throwing it off, to see which values are bound. Maybe the keys missing.

Comment: Any possible "trapdoor" code in the entity definitions that might be trying to change CODE_ID getting fired unexpectedly? Agree this is occurring before it ever goes out the door to Oracle; EF is thinking an illegal change is being attempted...

Comment: Can you post code for your model? Or part of it, it is simply that you have forgotten to put DatabaseGenerated attribute for one of your key column.

Answer (score 2):

Please include:

- The entity definition
- The mapping class / configuration from the context
- The SQL table definition

### BackPropagateServerGen

Looking at the stack trace, the key thing I see is `BackPropagateServerGen`.

Entity Framework is running your update against the database, but one of your composite key values (presumably COPY_ID) is actually being altered by the UPDATE call. This server-generated value is coming back from the SQL call, and Entity Framework is then complaining that the key value is being changed out from under it.

So, I would guess that your COPY_ID composite key value is defined as a server-generated identifier, but one or both of these is happening:

- You're mapping to a view or a stored procedure which is interfering with what Entity Framework would expect of a vanilla UPDATE
- You have one or more triggers on the table, view or stored procedure that is interfering with the result.

If you have any triggers, disable them temporarily to see if the problem then stops.

If you're mapping to a view or a stored procedure, try mapping directly to the table if possible.

Use whatever profiling tools you have to capture what SQL is being executed by the code.

### Summary

I think the UPDATE call is actually reaching the database, but the return result is changing the key value(s), causing Entity Framework to fail, and likely rolling back the UPDATE transaction (depending on what version of EF you're using).

Comment: Thanks David.  I have added a trace file to the question and you are right it is getting the database, the update is done and and the error is thrown on the return to EF.  We have checked the ID fields and it is the same numbers being sent to the database as being returned.   There are no triggers or stored procedures.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Oracle, so I'm unsure about the data types. Is it possible the data types between Oracle and Entity Framework are causing a precision / conversion issue? What happens if you map your composite key value as `long`, and then try `double`? It would be interesting to know how the return value is coming back from the SQL; is it recognizing it as 3 Int32 values, or an object or tuple and getting confused? Maybe logging can show us: `context.Database.Log = message => Trace.Write(message);`

Comment: You could also try changing the `DatabaseGeneratedOption` for the keys from `Generated` to `None` and see if that at least fixes your update statements. I find it strange that Entity Framework is checking for generated database key values on an update; maybe a sanity check? Seeing the mapping might help.