# ASP.NET webapi odata put, The property 'ID' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata

I am a nooby with ASP.NET webapi, and this is a very simple situation that i am stuck in.

I am using webapi+odata

My Model:

```
public class CategoryModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ParentID { get; set; }
}
```

My Auto Generated Controller's put method:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Put([FromODataUri] int key, Delta<CategoryModel> patch)
{
    Validate(patch.GetEntity());

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    CategoryModel categoryModel = await db.Category.FindAsync(key);
    if (categoryModel == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    patch.Put(categoryModel);

    try
    {
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
    {
        if (!CategoryModelExists(key))
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    return Updated(categoryModel);
}
```

And my jquery ajax

```
jQuery.ajax(
        {
          url       : '/api/Category(3)',
          data      : { Name:'New Category' },
          method    : 'PUT',
          headers   : {
            Accept        : 'application/json',
          },
          statusCode: {
            401: () => {
              console.log('handle the unautherized here');
            },
          },
          beforeSend: (jqXHR, settings) => {},
          error     : (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) => {
            //TODO do some global error reporting

            Util.Error(JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText));
            resolve(null);
          },
          success   : (data, textStatus, jqXHR) => {
            resolve(data);
          },
          complete  : (jqXHR, textStatus) => {}
        }
      );
```

and the error :

```
{
  "odata.error": {
    "code": "",
    "message": {
      "lang": "en-US",
      "value": "An error has occurred."
    },
    "innererror": {
      "message": "The property 'ID' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified. ",
      "type": "System.InvalidOperationException",
      "stacktrace": "   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.EntityEntry.DetectChangesInProperty(Int32 ordinal, Boolean detectOnlyComplexProperties, Boolean detectOnly)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.EntityEntry.DetectChangesInProperties(Boolean detectOnlyComplexProperties)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectStateManager.DetectChangesInScalarAndComplexProperties(IList`1 entries)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectStateManager.DetectChanges()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.DetectChanges()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.DetectChanges(Boolean force)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetStateEntries(Func`2 predicate)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetStateEntries()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbChangeTracker.Entries()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.GetValidationErrors()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync()\r\n   at Notifier.Controllers.CategoryController.<Put>d__3.MoveNext() in E:\\csharp\\notifier\\Notifier\\Notifier\\Controllers\\CategoryController.cs:line 66\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<CastToObject>d__3`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"
    }
```

`GET` and `POST` works ok, but `PUT` and `PATCH` giving me this error.

Help me please ...

UPDATE : The problem is with this controller's generated code with odata v3, I checked with normal webapi controller and it works just fine, so ....

Comment: you got error on ` await db.SaveChangesAsync();`?

Comment: @UmairAnwaar yes

Comment: Do you have primary key in database table?

Comment: Have you tried to get object using `SingleOrDefault` and set name then  put `db.Entry("modifiedObject").State = EntityState.Modiied; db.SaveChanges();`

Comment: @vanloc ID is the primary key, by default EF takes ID as primary if another one is not specified.

Comment: @Exlord Correct, because EF auto takes ID as a primary key. I think the problem at here. You cannot edit the primary key value here, is that it (the primary key) has been referenced by another table as a foreign key. You will have to drop/change any referencing rows in other tables in order to update this "Category.ID" column.

Comment: @Exlord Can you try to remove Table<Category> from EntityModel and Add it again! If it's not working, I think you should remove the `.edmx.' file and re-create it! An almost case, it will work. At least with me. Hope it helpful for you.

Comment: @vanloc That the thing I am not trying to change the `ID`, I am just Sending the `Name` property, And beside `Category` is the only table in my database :D

Comment: @vanloc I completely removed/deleted the database, and recreated it. Still the same

Comment: Sorry @Exlord , I really want to help you but I tried to found any solution for your problem but can't find. Can you see reference, I think it will helpful with you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31854053/6112401.

Comment: @vanloc tnx, I decided to go back to normal webapi for now, can't waste any more time on this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you're trying to update an object with an Id different from 3, however your ajax call is sending an Id = 3 which you've hard-coded in the line:

```
url       : '/api/Category(3)',
```

Comment: But the data OP is sending is in the next line: `data      : { Name:'New Category' },`, where there's no ID, and this is a PUT: they're trying to create a new object.

Comment: That said, this is probably impossible to actually answer without further clarification from them - which we generally ask as comments, not answers, once you have enough rep points to do so - and this is an old question so chances are they've moved on anyway. But thanks for trying to help!